# Android - decryption issues with AES encrypted string in QR code

Tags: android, cryptography, aes, encryption

I've built a QR code generator and a QR code scanner for passing data about phones and their users between phones (the phones are being loaned out so there will be a master phone with the scanner app and the rest with the generator app). The QR code generated is a JSON format string containing a persons name/number/imei of their phone but for security I have tried to encrypt the string before encoding to QR, but the scanned QR code throws up a 'pad block corrupted' error.

The JSON data encodes into QR/decodes from QR fine as plain text, and I checked the encryption/decryption before encoding to QR and the data encrypts/decrypts fine, so it's something to do with when the encrypted text is encoded into QR but I've no idea where to begin with it!

Does anyone know how i can sort the issue? Or if theres any QR friendly encryption methods?!!

I took the QRCodeEncoder straight from ZXings source and placed it into my activity:

```
/**QR ENCODER CLASS****************************************************/

    public class QRCodeEncoder
    {
        private final String TAG = QRCodeEncoder.class.getSimpleName();

          private static final int WHITE = 0xFFFFFFFF;
          private static final int BLACK = 0xFF000000;

          private final Activity activity;
          private String contents;
          private String displayContents;
          private String title;
          private BarcodeFormat format;
          private final int dimension;

          QRCodeEncoder(Activity activity, Intent intent, int dimension) {
                this.activity = activity;
                if (intent == null) {
                  throw new IllegalArgumentException("No valid data to encode. intent is null");
                }

                String action = intent.getAction();
                if (action.equals(Intents.Encode.ACTION)) {
                  if (!encodeContentsFromZXingIntent(intent)) {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("No valid data to encode. Zxing intent returned false");
                  }
                } else if (action.equals(Intent.ACTION_SEND)) {
                  if (!encodeContentsFromShareIntent(intent)) {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("No valid data to encode. Share Intent returned false");
                  }
                }

                this.dimension = dimension;
              }

              public String getContents() {
                return contents;
              }

              public String getDisplayContents() {
                return displayContents;
              }

              public String getTitle() {
                return title;
              }

              // It would be nice if the string encoding lived in the core ZXing library,
              // but we use platform specific code like PhoneNumberUtils, so it can't.
              private boolean encodeContentsFromZXingIntent(Intent intent) {
                 // Default to QR_CODE if no format given.
                String formatString = intent.getStringExtra(Intents.Encode.FORMAT);
                try {
                  format = BarcodeFormat.valueOf(formatString);
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException iae) {
                  // Ignore it then
                  format = null;
                }
                if (format == null || BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE.equals(format)) {
                  String type = intent.getStringExtra(Intents.Encode.TYPE);
                  if (type == null || type.length() == 0) {
                    return false;
                  }
                  this.format = BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE;
                  encodeQRCodeContents(intent, type);
                } else {
                  String data = intent.getStringExtra(Intents.Encode.DATA);
                  if (data != null && data.length() > 0) {
                    contents = data;
                    displayContents = data;
                    title = "QR Encoder";
                  }
                }
                return contents != null && contents.length() > 0;
              }

              // Handles send intents from multitude of Android applications
              private boolean encodeContentsFromShareIntent(Intent intent) {
                // Check if this is a plain text encoding, or contact
                if (intent.hasExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT)) {
                  return encodeContentsFromShareIntentPlainText(intent);
                }
                // Attempt default sharing.
                return encodeContentsFromShareIntentDefault(intent);
              }

              private boolean encodeContentsFromShareIntentPlainText(Intent intent) {
                // Notice: Google Maps shares both URL and details in one text, bummer!
                contents = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"contents read = "+contents,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                // We only support non-empty and non-blank texts.
                // Trim text to avoid URL breaking.
                if (contents == null) {
                  return false;
                }
                contents = contents.trim();
                if (contents.length() == 0) {
                  return false;
                }
                // We only do QR code.
                format = BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE;
                if (intent.hasExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT)) {
                  displayContents = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT);
                } else if (intent.hasExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE)) {
                  displayContents = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE);
                } else {
                  displayContents = contents;
                }
                title = "QR Encoder";
                return true;
              }

              // Handles send intents from the Contacts app, retrieving a contact as a VCARD.
              // Note: Does not work on HTC devices due to broken custom Contacts application.
              private boolean encodeContentsFromShareIntentDefault(Intent intent) {
                format = BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE;
                try {
                  Uri uri = (Uri)intent.getExtras().getParcelable(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
                  InputStream stream = activity.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
                  int length = stream.available();
                  if (length <= 0) {
                    Log.w(TAG, "Content stream is empty");
                    return false;
                  }
                  byte[] vcard = new byte[length];
                  int bytesRead = stream.read(vcard, 0, length);
                  if (bytesRead < length) {
                    Log.w(TAG, "Unable to fully read available bytes from content stream");
                    return false;
                  }
                  String vcardString = new String(vcard, 0, bytesRead, "UTF-8");
                  Log.d(TAG, "Encoding share intent content:");
                  Log.d(TAG, vcardString);
                  Result result = new Result(vcardString, vcard, null, BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE);
                  ParsedResult parsedResult = ResultParser.parseResult(result);
                  if (!(parsedResult instanceof AddressBookParsedResult)) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Result was not an address");
                    return false;
                  }
                  if (!encodeQRCodeContents((AddressBookParsedResult) parsedResult)) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Unable to encode contents");
                    return false;
                  }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                  Log.w(TAG, e);
                  return false;
                } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                  Log.w(TAG, e);
                  // In case the uri was not found in the Intent.
                  return false;
                }
                return contents != null && contents.length() > 0;
              }

              private void encodeQRCodeContents(Intent intent, String type) {
                if (type.equals(Contents.Type.TEXT)) {
                  String data = intent.getStringExtra(Intents.Encode.DATA);
                  if (data != null && data.length() > 0) {
                    contents = data;
                    displayContents = data;
                    title = "QR Encoder";
                  }
                } else if (type.equals(Contents.Type.EMAIL)) {
                  String data = trim(intent.getStringExtra(Intents.Encode.DATA));
                  if (data != null) {
                    contents = "mailto:" + data;
                    displayContents = data;
                    title = "QR Encoder";
                  }
                } else if (type.equals(Contents.Type.PHONE)) {
                  String data = trim(intent.getStringExtra(Intents.Encode.DATA));
                  if (data != null) {
                    contents = "tel:" + data;
                    displayContents = PhoneNumberUtils.formatNumber(data);
                    title = "QR Encoder";
                  }
                } else if (type.equals(Contents.Type.SMS)) {
                  String data = trim(intent.getStringExtra(Intents.Encode.DATA));
                  if (data != null) {
                    contents = "sms:" + data;
                    displayContents = PhoneNumberUtils.formatNumber(data);
                    title = "QR Encoder";
                  }
                } else if (type.equals(Contents.Type.CONTACT)) {
                  Bundle bundle = intent.getBundleExtra(Intents.Encode.DATA);
                  if (bundle != null) {
                    StringBuilder newContents = new StringBuilder(100);
                    StringBuilder newDisplayContents = new StringBuilder(100);
                    newContents.append("MECARD:");
                    String name = trim(bundle.getString(Contacts.Intents.Insert.NAME));
                    if (name != null) {
                      newContents.append("N:").append(escapeMECARD(name)).append(';');
                      newDisplayContents.append(name);
                    }
                    String address = trim(bundle.getString(Contacts.Intents.Insert.POSTAL));
                    if (address != null) {
                      newContents.append("ADR:").append(escapeMECARD(address)).append(';');
                      newDisplayContents.append('\n').append(address);
                    }
                    for (int x = 0; x < Contents.PHONE_KEYS.length; x++) {
                      String phone = trim(bundle.getString(Contents.PHONE_KEYS[x]));
                      if (phone != null) {
                        newContents.append("TEL:").append(escapeMECARD(phone)).append(';');
                        newDisplayContents.append('\n').append(PhoneNumberUtils.formatNumber(phone));
                      }
                    }
                    for (int x = 0; x < Contents.EMAIL_KEYS.length; x++) {
                      String email = trim(bundle.getString(Contents.EMAIL_KEYS[x]));
                      if (email != null) {
                        newContents.append("EMAIL:").append(escapeMECARD(email)).append(';');
                        newDisplayContents.append('\n').append(email);
                      }
                    }
                    // Make sure we've encoded at least one field.
                    if (newDisplayContents.length() > 0) {
                      newContents.append(';');
                      contents = newContents.toString();
                      displayContents = newDisplayContents.toString();
                      title = "QR Encoder";
                    } else {
                      contents = null;
                      displayContents = null;
                    }
                  }
                } else if (type.equals(Contents.Type.LOCATION)) {
                  Bundle bundle = intent.getBundleExtra(Intents.Encode.DATA);
                  if (bundle != null) {
                    // These must use Bundle.getFloat(), not getDouble(), it's part of the API.
                    float latitude = bundle.getFloat("LAT", Float.MAX_VALUE);
                    float longitude = bundle.getFloat("LONG", Float.MAX_VALUE);
                    if (latitude != Float.MAX_VALUE && longitude != Float.MAX_VALUE) {
                      contents = "geo:" + latitude + ',' + longitude;
                      displayContents = latitude + "," + longitude;
                      title = "QR Encoder";
                    }
                  }
                }
              }

              private boolean encodeQRCodeContents(AddressBookParsedResult contact) {
                StringBuilder newContents = new StringBuilder(100);
                StringBuilder newDisplayContents = new StringBuilder(100);
                newContents.append("MECARD:");
                String[] names = contact.getNames();
                if (names != null && names.length > 0) {
                  String name = trim(names[0]);
                  if (name != null) {
                    newContents.append("N:").append(escapeMECARD(name)).append(';');
                    newDisplayContents.append(name);
                  }
                }
                String[] addresses = contact.getAddresses();
                if (addresses != null) {
                  for (String address : addresses) {
                    address = trim(address);
                    if (address != null) {
                      newContents.append("ADR:").append(escapeMECARD(address)).append(';');
                      newDisplayContents.append('\n').append(address);
                    }
                  }
                }
                String[] phoneNumbers = contact.getPhoneNumbers();
                if (phoneNumbers != null) {
                  for (String phone : phoneNumbers) {
                    phone = trim(phone);
                    if (phone != null) {
                      newContents.append("TEL:").append(escapeMECARD(phone)).append(';');
                      newDisplayContents.append('\n').append(PhoneNumberUtils.formatNumber(phone));
                    }
                  }
                }
                String[] emails = contact.getEmails();
                if (emails != null) {
                  for (String email : emails) {
                    email = trim(email);
                    if (email != null) {
                      newContents.append("EMAIL:").append(escapeMECARD(email)).append(';');
                      newDisplayContents.append('\n').append(email);
                    }
                  }
                }
                String url = trim(contact.getURL());
                if (url != null) {
                  newContents.append("URL:").append(escapeMECARD(url)).append(';');
                  newDisplayContents.append('\n').append(url);
                }
                // Make sure we've encoded at least one field.
                if (newDisplayContents.length() > 0) {
                  newContents.append(';');
                  contents = newContents.toString();
                  displayContents = newDisplayContents.toString();
                  title = "QR Encoder";
                  return true;
                } else {
                  contents = null;
                  displayContents = null;
                  return false;
                }
              }

              Bitmap encodeAsBitmap() throws WriterException {
                Hashtable<EncodeHintType,Object> hints = null;
                String encoding = guessAppropriateEncoding(contents);
                if (encoding != null) {
                  hints = new Hashtable<EncodeHintType,Object>(2);
                  hints.put(EncodeHintType.CHARACTER_SET, encoding);
                }
                MultiFormatWriter writer = new MultiFormatWriter();
                BitMatrix result = writer.encode(contents, format, dimension, dimension, hints);
                int width = result.getWidth();
                int height = result.getHeight();
                int[] pixels = new int[width * height];
                // All are 0, or black, by default
                for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
                  int offset = y * width;
                  for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
                    pixels[offset + x] = result.get(x, y) ? BLACK : WHITE;
                  }
                }

                Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                bitmap.setPixels(pixels, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);
                return bitmap;
              }

              private String guessAppropriateEncoding(CharSequence contents) {
                // Very crude at the moment
                for (int i = 0; i < contents.length(); i++) {
                  if (contents.charAt(i) > 0xFF) {
                    return "UTF-8";
                  }
                }
                return null;
              }

              private String trim(String s) {
                if (s == null) {
                  return null;
                }
                s = s.trim();
                return s.length() == 0 ? null : s;
              }

              private String escapeMECARD(String input) {
                if (input == null || (input.indexOf(':') < 0 && input.indexOf(';') < 0)) {
                  return input;
                }
                int length = input.length();
                StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(length);
                for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                  char c = input.charAt(i);
                  if (c == ':' || c == ';') {
                    result.append('\\');
                  }
                  result.append(c);
                }
                return result.toString();
              }
    }
```

And the encryption/decryption class from [this website (unedited)](http://www.androidsnippets.com/encryptdecrypt-strings)

Here's a snippet of the onCreate() method in my activity:

```
QRCodeEncoder myQRCodeEncoder;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.qr_view);
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.qr_image);

            extStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
            try
            {

                //JSON data is passed from another activity to this one
                qrMessage = getIntent().getStringExtra("QR_JSON");

                Intent encode = new Intent(Intents.Encode.ACTION);
                encode.putExtra(Intents.Encode.TYPE, Contents.Type.TEXT);
                encode.putExtra(Intents.Encode.FORMAT, "QR_CODE");
                    //This is the original plain text way that works:
                //encode.putExtra(Intents.Encode.DATA, qrMessage);

                    //This is the encyption way
                String encMessage = SimpleCrypto.encrypt("my s3cr3t k3y", qrMessage);
                encode.putExtra(Intents.Encode.DATA,encMessage);


                myQRCodeEncoder = new QRCodeEncoder(this, encode, 200);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Could not encode:"+e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            catch(Error e)
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Could not encode:"+e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }


            try {
                Bitmap qrBitmap = myQRCodeEncoder.encodeAsBitmap();
                imageView.setImageBitmap(qrBitmap);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Could not set image:"+e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
            }
    }
```

And here's the onActivityResult method from the scanner (I use ZXing's barcode scanner to retrieve the data)

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    if (requestCode == 0) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            String contents = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");//contents of the scan
            String format = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT");
            // Handle successful scan

            /* display the scanned persons info*/
            try {
                String decryptedcontents = SimpleCrypto.decrypt("my s3cr3t k3y",contents);
                String result = getJSONFromScanData(decryptedcontents);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                Toast.makeText(this, "Scanned data could not be decrypted:"+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();//says 'pad block corrupted' as the message
            }



        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // Handle cancel
            Toast.makeText(this, "Scan cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: after some further investigation it seems that the encyption/decyption process seems to 'shave off' part of the data:

```
 JSONObject example = new JSONObject("{\"user_firstname\":\"Ben\",\"user_lastname\":\" Ten\",\"user_login\":\"benten\",\"user_pass\":\"password\",\"user_email\":\"benten@domain.com\"}");
                String mess = SimpleCrypto.encrypt("my s3cr3t k3y",example.toString());
String decrmess = SimpleCrypto.decrypt("my s3cr3t k3y",mess));
//decypts as:{"user_pass":"password","user_email":"benten@domain.com","user_login":"benten","user_lastname":"
```

as you can see only 96 characters are decrypted, theres no user_firstname or the users actual last name, the data is missing, but this number is inconsistent, I changed the user_email to "benbenten@domain.com" and the user_firstname to "benben" and 112 characters were decrypted...I am completely stumped

EDIT 2: Yngve Ådlandsvik has kindly pointed me in the right direction (many thanks again!) that the string length needed to be a multiple of 16, so I set the Cipher.getInstance in both the encrypt and decrypt methods to:

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/NoPadding","BC");
```

and in my main activity set a loop to add 0's on the end of my string as custom padding before encrypting:

```
boolean carryOn = true;
                while(carryOn)
                {
                    int paddedLength = qrMessage.getBytes().length;
                    int checkMultiple16 = paddedLength%16;
                    if(checkMultiple16==0)
                    {
                        carryOn = false;
                    }
                    else
                    qrMessage+="0";
                }
```

EDIT 3: It looks like QR encoding still screws with the encryption, I can't decrypt the scanned in data properly, looks like QR encoding does something with strings before it encodes to QR which seems to break the thing, guess I'll have to stick to unencrypted text in the QR...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't read the code closely, but I assume this happens because AES only operates on blocks of 16 bytes at once. So my guess is you need to manually apply some form of [reversible padding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_%28cryptography%29#Byte_padding) to your string before encryption so it becomes a multiple of 16, and then reverse the padding after decryption.

You could also change the Cipher.getInstance() strings in the crypto code so the encryption will support padding natively, though I don't know which padding types and cipher modes are available on Android.

Comment: That was indeed spot on advice!!! I had to set the Cipher.getInstance to `Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/NoPadding","BC");` and in my main activity I had a loop to check to see if the byte length of my string is a multiple of 16, and if not, add a '0' to the end of the string (I'll update my original post with the code)

Many thanks for this :)

Comment: Try using PKCS#7 padding if it's available. It is advisable NOT to use ECB. Use CTR or CBC.

Comment: I originally tried with PKCS#7 padding and still got the cutting off of text, the way i explained previously seemed to be the only option...
Also regarding ECB/CTR/CBC, could you please explain the difference between them? I got an error about the iv being 0 when I changed ECB to CBC

Comment: For the difference between ECB, CBC and CTR see [block Cypher modes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_modes).  As Ranhiru says, don't use ECB.  Use CBC or CTR instead.